# Python 3.8 How to read line message following msg = get_message(service, user_id, msg_id) command?

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm hoping this question can be answered without running the code since there is an added Google API process needed to first perform in order to build a private logon key needed to run the script.

However, just in case it is needed, I am copying the entire script.  It's somewhat difficult to describe the problem, so I hope you are patient with me and I appreciate in advance any help provided.  Here we go ...

Using Python, I am running Google's API authentication to Read my Gmail.  My ultimate goal is to read each line of the Gmail message, and parse the email into separate messages.  After the call "msg = get_message(service, user_id, msg_id)" command, I run print(msg).  The printout below looks good.

*Send Ops-problem-detail mailing list submissions to
ops-problem-detail@lists.cenic.org
To subscribe or unsubscribe via the World Wide Web, visit
https://lists.cenic.org/mailman/listinfo/ops-problem-detail
or, via email, send a message with subject or body 'help' to
ops-problem-detail-request@lists.cenic.org
You can reach the person managing the list at
ops-problem-detail-owner@lists.cenic.org
When replying, please edit your Subject line so it is more specific
than "Re: Contents of Ops-problem-detail digest..."*

**What I need to do:**
But then, I discovered that I do not know the correct command to loop through each of the lines in the above message so that I can reference any one of the words or characters on the line.  So, for example, after I read the line "*Send Ops-problem-detail mailing list submissions to*" I want to be able to reference the word "*mailing*" on the line and assign it to a variable.

**Question**
How do I read line by line in the **msg** so I can access data within each line as I loop through the message?

Code in Action (Example):

1. I first generated a credentials.json file per Google instructions.
2. I copied the Python code (below) and ran the script with this added command, **service = get_service()**
3. I run command, user_id = "me"
4. And then this command, search_message(service, user_id, "Ops-problem-detail").
   Steps 2-4 above look like this:
   service = get_service()
   user_id = "me"
   search_message(service, user_id, "Ops-problem-detail")
5. The following Message IDs were the result:
   ['*175b3be801509c54*',
   '175b1ab1332bfc13',
   '175b080629f60110',
   '175ae981cf3134a7',
   '175ae150c70badb2',
6. Now that I have *message IDs*, I can run the script to look at one of the messages for my simple test case:

msg_id = '*175b3be801509c54*'
msg = get_message(service, user_id, msg_id)
print(msg)

7. The result is the print out below:

*Send Ops-mm-detail mailing list submissions to
ops-problem-detail@lists.nn.org
To subscribe or unsubscribe via the World Wide Web, visit
https://lists.nn.org/mailman/listinfo/nn-problem-detail
or, via email, send a message with subject or body 'help' to
mm-problem-detail-request@lists.nn.org
You can reach the person managing the list at
mm-problem-detail-owner@lists.nn.org
When replying, please edit your Subject line so it is more specific
than "Re: Contents of mm-problem-detail digest..."*

What I want to do, is loop through each of the lines of the above print(msg) so I can access any of the words on each line for further development.

**How do I do this?**

Code:
'''
#!/usr/python

```
import pickle
import os.path
from apiclient import errors
import email
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import base64

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def search_message(service, user_id, search_string):

    #Search the inbox for emails using standard gmail search parameters
    #and return a list of email IDs for each result
    #PARAMS:
        #service: the google api service object already instantiated
        #user_id: user id for google api service ('me' works here if
        #already authenticated)
        #search_string: search operators you can use with Gmail
        #(see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en for a list)
        
    #RETURNS:
        #List containing email IDs of search query
     try:
        # initiate the list for returning
        list_ids = []

        # get the id of all messages that are in the search string
        search_ids = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=search_string).execute()
        
        # if there were no results, print warning and return empty string
        try:
            ids = search_ids['messages']

        except KeyError:
            print("WARNING: the search queried returned 0 results")
            print("returning an empty string")
            return ""

        if len(ids)>1:
            for msg_id in ids:
                list_ids.append(msg_id['id'])
            return(list_ids)

        else:
            list_ids.append(ids['id'])
            return list_ids
        
    except (errors.HttpError, error):
        print("An error occured: %s") % error


def get_message(service, user_id, msg_id):

#    Search the inbox for specific message by ID and return it back as a 
#    clean string. String may contain Python escape characters for newline
#    and return line. 
#    
#    PARAMS
#        service: the google api service object already instantiated
#        user_id: user id for google api service ('me' works here if
#        already authenticated)
#        msg_id: the unique id of the email you need
#    RETURNS
#        A string of encoded text containing the message body

    try:
        # grab the message instance
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,format='raw').execute()

        # decode the raw string, ASCII works pretty well here
        msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

        # grab the string from the byte object
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)

        # check if the content is multipart (it usually is)
        content_type = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
        if content_type == 'multipart':
            # there will usually be 2 parts the first will be the body in text
            # the second will be the text in html
            parts = mime_msg.get_payload()

            # return the encoded text
            final_content = parts[0].get_payload()
            return final_content

        elif content_type == 'text':
            return mime_msg.get_payload()

        else:
            return ""
            print("\nMessage is not text or multipart, returned an empty string")
    # unsure why the usual exception doesn't work in this case, but 
    # having a standard Exception seems to do the trick
    except Exception:
        print("An error occured: %s") % error


def get_service():

#    Authenticate the google api client and return the service object 
#    to make further calls
#    PARAMS
#        None
#    RETURNS
#        service api object from gmail for making calls

    creds = None

    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)


    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    return service
```

Answer (score 0):

And I figured it out.  I wound up writing the message to a temporary file before looping through each line.  There may be a better way, but it works and I can move on.  After that it was just a matter of opening and begin looping through the lines:

first write the message to a file: text_file.write(str(msg))

And then, in this parsing portion of the script:

def parse_msg():
file = open('one.txt', 'r')

```
split_string = "------------------------------"
key_string = "Message:"

string = ""
final_list = []

for line in file:
```

etc ...